# NSUTF8StringEncoding not working when decoding the same message

Tags: swift, utf-8, ios9.3.2

I am trying to send emojis in a chat app, and to send those I have to encode and decode string to and from NSUTF8StringEncoding. The decoded/encoded message is displayed in a cell.

It displays correctly while sending (encoding) but doesn't work while receiving (decoding).

Encoding Code:

```
var data = NSData()
data = (self.message?.dataUsingEncoding(NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding))!
let encodedMessage = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Decoding Code:

```
let data = self.message!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let decodedMessage = String(data: data!, encoding: NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)
```

Device 1 (version 9.3):

[image: Device 1]

Device 2 (Version 9.3.2):

[image: Device 2]

Comment: A concrete example of input message, encoded and decoded message would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem wasn't in decoding or encoding. The receiving and sending cells were different, and while displaying text in receiving cell the data wasn't decoded. So decoding it there as well worked.